# Memory leak with Qwt

Tags: c++, qt, memory, memory-leaks, qwt

I am developing a small plotter application with `Qt 5.8` and `Qwt 6.1.3`. Though I think I understand Qwt's memory management approach correctly, I seem to have memory leaks in my application due to `QwtPlotItem`s I'm using; such as `QwtPlotMarker` and `QwtPlotCurve`. I have read [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50889-A-problem-with-memory-management) and [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/57048-What-to-explicitely-delete-in-qwt) as well as the documentation. I follow the rules given there, however I still have memory leaks with plot items.

In my application there is a `QwtPlot` object that is alive at all times while the application is running. Plot items such as `QwtPlotMarker` and `QwtPlotCurve` are being `attach()`-ed and `detach()`-ed during run time. What I do is, I don't call `delete` for any `QwtPlotItem`, I use raw pointers for Qwt objects.

I'm not sure if once a `QwtPlotITem` is `detach()`-ed it is also deleted. I have seen [`void QwtPlotDict::removeItem(QwtPlotItem* item)`](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_dict.html#abd0227e8b888b40b4e62a23f6040c6cd) in the documentation and I'm not sure if I should use it to delete `attach()`-ed `QwtPlotItem`s, because what it seems is that after `detach()`, `QwtPlotItem`s are still alive on the heap.

I would appreciate any guidance regarding memory management in Qwt.

**Update**:

Below is a better example. Without the second for loop where I'm `detach()`-ing `QwtPlotCurve`s, memory usage is 8.2 Mbs. With the second for loop but without the `delete v[i]; // MANUALLY DELETING QWTPLOTITEM OBJECT`, memory usage is still 8.2 Mbs. With the second for loop AND the `delete v[i]; // MANUALLY DELETING QWTPLOTITEM OBJECT` line, the memory usage is 5.2 Mbs. So I think it is needed to manually delete `QwtPlotItem`s in Qwt.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QwtPlot* plot = new QwtPlot;

    std::vector<QwtPlotCurve*> v;
    double x[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    double y1[5] = {0, 1.5, 0.3, 2.7, 3.0};
    double y2[5] = {0, 0.5, 0.2, 2.0, 1.6};

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        double y1[5] = {0*i, 1.5*i, 0.3*i, 2.7*i, 3.0*i};
        QwtPlotCurve* plotCurve1 = new QwtPlotCurve("CurveXY1");
        plotCurve1->setSamples(&x[0], &y1[0], 5);
        plotCurve1->attach(plot);
        v.push_back(plotCurve1);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 1900; i++) {
        v[i]->detach();
        delete v[i]; // MANUALLY DELETING QWTPLOTITEM OBJECT
    }

    plot->replot();
    plot->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

In above example, both `if()`s have conditions that are `true`. So `plotCurve2` was not deleted after `detach()`.

Comment: Try using a program like **valgrind**, and please post a [MCVE]

Comment: I have added a small example that shows that `detach()` does not `null` the `QwtPlotItem` pointer (`plotCurve2` in my example).

Comment: Just delete it your self (you `new`'ed it): `delete plotCurve2`

Comment: @Jonas In the link I've given in my original post, it is adviced not to call `delete` on `QwtPlotItem`s. However, my example shows that it is indeed needed to call `delete` on them after `detach()`.

Comment: You are creating 2000 objects but only deleting 1900...

Comment: @JvO I know. The point is to show that there is a difference in memory usage between the code with `delete` and the code without `delete`. You might delete all 2000 objects, it would only give you less memory used when delete is called. I basically wanted to delete only 1900 of them to simulate a more general situation, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the forum posts regarding pointer ownership.

In qwt, QwtPlotItems are all owned by the QwtPlot that they are `attach()`ed to, so if you delete that plot, all of the QwtPlotItems will be deleted.

If you call `detach()`, then ownership is transferred to the caller, so you need to delete it yourself (or `.attach()` it to another plot). If it were deleted for you then attaching to another plot would not be possible.

`item.detach(); delete item` is perfectly fine regarding memory management, and the delete *is* necessary.

An alternative would be to just delete it directly (without calling `.detach()`). The destructor will detach it for you, and then there are no ownership questions or risks of memory leaks.

A further alternative would be to store a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<QwtPlotItem>>` (or QList std::set/whatever container you want) and just erase them from the vector when you are done. That will definitely not have memory leaks, but you need to ensure that the vector is created after the plot and destroyed before it, or you will get double deletes (e.g. place the vector afterwards on the stack, or after the plot inside your object).

Comment: Thank you. This makes perfect sense. And yes, you are right, I misunderstood the ownership concept. Since my QwtPlot object is alive at all times, it does not really delete any QwtPlotItems. And the unique_ptr approach you suggest seems like a better option than the manual delete approach. I will need to see how I can implement these in my program though, but your answer cleared the confusion in my understanding. I also want to credit Jonas's answer, since they were basically suggesting the same approach. Thank you both.